# Replace nan with NOT KNOWN

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) that looks like:

```
   ColumnA
0        1
1        1
2        1
3      nan
4        1
```

I am trying to replace the `nan` with `NOT KNOWN`. So the output looks like:

```
         ColumnA
0              1
1              1
2              1
3      NOT KNOWN
4              1
```

I however am having a battle trying to get this to work.

I have tried the following without success:

```
df["ColumnA"].replace(np.nan,"NOT KNOWN", inplace=True)
df["ColumnA"] = df["ColumnA"].replace(np.nan, 'NOT KNOWN', regex=True)
df["ColumnA"] = df["ColumnA"] .fillna('NOT KNOWN')
df["ColumnA"] = df["ColumnA"].replace('', 'NOT KNOWN', regex=True)
```

I don't know if it's to do with what I'm trying to replace being `nan` and not `NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `nan` is string (because failed with code from question), so use:

```
df["ColumnA"] = df["ColumnA"].replace('nan', 'NOT KNOWN')
```

Or solution with `inplace` parameter, thank you @Jon Clements:

```
df['ColumnA'].replace('nan', 'NOT KNOWN', inplace=True)

df.loc[df['ColumnA'] == 'nan', 'ColumnA'] = 'NOT KNOWN'
```

Comment: Maybe even `df['ColumnA'].replace('nan', 'NOT KNOWN', inplace=True)`? Or if the power of replace isn't really needed, then: `df.loc[df['ColumnA'] == 'nan', 'ColumnA'] = 'NOT KNOWN'`...

Comment: @JonClements - Thank you. Btw, interesting part of tutorial about `inplace` is [here](http://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html)